# Accessing variables of subviews from uipageviewcontroller class/passing variable values across views

Tags: ios, objective-c, subview, uipageviewcontroller

I am implementing something very similar to the stock app on iPhone. I have got the graph to render successfully and I have also implemented the time granularity feature they got for the stocks (1w, 1d, 1M, etc). My problem is I don't know how I can pass on the chosen time granularity from one view to another while swiping.

For example:
I have a:
1. `UIPageViewController` and then have 3 subviews where each views renders a graph
2. Each of the 3 subviews have 4 buttons (to view graph for 1day, 1week, 1hour or 1month)

If I click the "1day" button I want the next graph to default itself to "1day" and have that button selected. The same applies to other buttons as well.

I just can't seem to find a clean way of passing the button selected from the previous view the new view that gets loaded. I've experimented a lot by adding code in the `pageviewcontroller` class functions such as :
`willTransitionToViewControllers`, `transitionCompleted`, `viewControllerBeforeViewController` and `viewControllerAfterViewController`
but to no avail! :(

For starters, if someone could at least help me with passing a string from one view to another that would be great (would be great if you can give me a small example).

For example, I have a

```
@proper NSString *tmp;
In View1: tmp = @"day";
```

When the user swipes from `view1` to `view2`, I want `view2` to have `@"day"` when its "`viewDidAppear`" method gets called. Really appreciate some help!

Comment: I solved my problem using the below code after reading up on NSUserDefaults. This helps me restore data even after the app is restarted which is quite amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using the below code after reading up on NSUserDefaults. This helps me restore data even after the app is restarted which is cool. I call storeFoo in "viewDidDisappear" and call restoreFoo in "viewDidAppear".

Since I did not get any answer, I am answering my own question which may benefit others facing a similar problem.

```
-(NSString *)storeFoo {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults;
    NSString *gran_store;

    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    store = [defaults objectForKey:@"someText"];

    if (store == nil) {
       store = @"test";
    }
    return store;
}
```

And the code to retrieve the stored string would be:

```
-(NSString *)restoreFoo {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults;
    NSString *store;

    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    store = [defaults objectForKey:@"someText"];

    if (store == nil) {
        store = @"something";    //In case you want to default to a string if NULL
    }
    return store;
}
```